# How to use chrome devtools to debug javascript running in a custom VM?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, blink

Here's my scenario:

I've created a little javascript VM implemented in pure javascript. The VM is very simple, but it can do basic things like pause/resume execution, as well as report source/line numbers of the currently executing bytecode.

What I want is to use chrome developer tools to debug code running inside my VM which will itself be running in a normal web page. Does chrome developer tools exposes some kind of API that lets me do that? In other words: Is there some way to control the dev tools debugger from javascript code that is being executed in a normal web page?

Any direction on the subject is appreciated, even if I have to write a custom chrome extension to achieve that.

Comment: chrome.devtools.panels API allows you to create a custom panel served by HTML & JavaScript. You can implement your own debugger as the new panel.

Comment: sourcemaps, probably.